# Numerical Methods for finding the inverse of a function

Tags: numerical-methods, signal-processing, inverse-function

So I have an input function $f(t)$ and an output function $h(t)$ such that,

$g(f(t)) = h(t)$

I was wondering if anyone knew of any numerical methods to find $g$ or its inverse?

More explicitly I have a function,

$f(V(t)) = \frac{|\zeta(t)|^2}{\int_t^\infty |\zeta(s)|^2 ds}$

$V(t)$ and $\zeta(t)$ are known and stored so calculating $f(V(t))$ isn't hard. What I want to know is given an arbitrary $\zeta(t)$ what should $V(t)$ be? For that I need to know $f^{-1}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $g(t)=h(f^{-1}(t))$, so the question boils down to numerical methods for finding $f^{-1}$. Well, for any particular value of $t$, you're just trying to solve $f(x)=t$, and the usual numericalmethods such as Newton's Method should apply.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=342551&tstart=0 for a pretty good approximation.

Comment: Hi Claude. Sorry about my lack of clarity. Gamma in this is not the Gamma function. It was just a function. I've edited the post to reflect the change.